# Map Reduce Simulator

Tags: java, file, hadoop, mapreduce, bandwidth

I want to implement Map Reduce simulation without actually doing any processing in the mapper & reducer phase, which means that I want to just do the data movement. Taking a file from the disk (i.e input) splitting it based on the split size (total input size/split size). Based on this splitting I create Mapper threads which run concurrently,having a splitted file each.Now for the shuffling phase I need to just grow the amount of the file so that it create little traffic as it would in real execution.And then in reduce phase just collecting the file based on the factor of 0.95 ( * mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum). Apart from all this I need to capture the bandwidth from each phase.

Can anyone please provide me with the idea of how to do it in java and which would be the best way to do.

*I dont want to use hadoop so I want to develop a simple program which does all this.

Please help me out with this. Thanks in advance for all your brilliant ideas and comments.

Comment: What bandwidth do you want to measure there? Of your hard disk? There are thousands of benchmarking tools for that.

Comment: Setting up a Hadoop VM doesn't take that long. Recreating the processes of HDFS and MapReduce would take far longer.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut How much bandwidth is being used to send the output from map,ouput from shuffle and output from reducer. Can you name some. Do you know any site or paper, which has the benchmark like how much data is generated during map shuffle and reduce phase for wordcount terasort and kmeans.

Comment: @cricket_007 My constraint is I should not use Hadoop and implement in a simple Map reduce framework

Comment: It is simple to do a streaming job in linux... but the whole threading, splitting, and shuffling process is not "simple". A data-flow would look like `STDIN > some_mapper | sort | some_reducer > STDOUT`, where `sort` is the built-in command